# Validate End date is greater than start date in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I want to validate `Start date` and `End date` how should I write in web resource?

I have tried some code but it doesn't work. The function is continuously repeating after some time. But it should be stop once executed.

Please help me on this.

```js
function ValidateEndDate(econtext) 
{
  var sdate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_startdate");
  var edate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_enddate");
  var eventArgs = econtext.getEventArgs();

  if (sdate.getValue() > edate.getValue())
  {
    alert("End date should be greater than");

    sdate.setValue(null);
    eventArgs.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: please describe what you mean by "they wont work" - the logic here seems fine.  Also, why is this function "continuously repeat after some time"?  this seems like it should just run when you try to save the record and block the save if the condition specified is met.

Comment: Because of "Auto save" is  enables automatic save of records.So.I did an other way to validate Start date and End date.I have used business rules in mscrm2015.

Comment: Please list your solution as an answer.